# New Kitten isn't eating or drinking

Tags: cats

My family adopted a new kitten (14 weeks old, female) last night and as we're first time cat owners we're a little unsure of if our kitten's behaviour is normal. We've restricted her to one *low traffic* room temporarily as we read that this is beneficial for kittens to get used to a new environment, but she's hidden under the dressing table and hasn't come out since last night. She has food, water, scratch post and an igloo bed but won't use any of them. We're a little worried that she will start to become dehydrated if she doesn't come out for a drink soon. Is this behaviour normal and how do we support her moving forward?

Comment: Its hard to be sure on water unless you have a camera or some other form of monitoring. Are you giving her the same kind of food she got before?

Comment: We only moved a camera indoors this morning so she may have secretly drank before we did this. We've kept her food the same. She's started to venture around the room now but unfortunately still no eating or drinking

Comment: has she started eating and drinking water now,if not you will have to take her to the vet now.